# Raspberry Pi error with ParsePy and six.py

Tags: python, parse-platform, raspberry-pi, six, parsepy

I am trying to connect my raspberry pi to parse.com wit ParsePy which uses the rest-api from parse.com. I am writing some python code to get it to work and I have an error with the classes supplied by ParsePy. In particular its the datatypes.py class.

It seems that when I run the code when it states import six, it cannot see it.

The errors I get is NameError:name 'six' is not defined.

What can I do so that I gets the right class?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the `six` module.

There is probably an installable package available with `apt-get install python-six`; you can also install it using `pip` or `easy_install` (e.g., `pip install six`).

Comment: There was a problem with the software I was using. The program idle did not recognize the six package. Don't know why. However, when running my python scripts from command line made everything work.